GDB convenience variable not expanded
Convenience variables on my macos are not expanded when using arm-gdb-none-eabi:
(gdb) set $foo = "bar"
(gdb) p $foo
$11 = "b"

However - this seems to be a print issue, as the value is correctly stored:
(gdb) set $foo = "bar"
(gdb) p/x $foo
$12 = {0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x0}
(gdb) ptype $foo
type = char [4]


Do you maybe have a (broken) pretty-printer? Try disable pretty-printer before p $foo.

Tried it now and it does not work for me. Thanks for suggesting though.

Do char * strings from the executable print correctly? Also, what gdb version do you use? Maybe there is a newer one you could try?
